# fio: blocksize too large for data set

Tags: docker, io, containers, kubernetes, benchmarking

I want to benchmark my SSD using Fio (Flexible I/O) I/O benchmarking tool inside Docker containers.

I am running my Docker containers like

`docker run -it -v /dev/nvme0n1:/mount saurabhd04/docker_fio`

where I am mounting my SSD as a Docker volume.

But, whenever I run fio inside Docker container, I get following error:

`fio: blocksize too large for data set`.

Am I missing anything? Any help regarding this would be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

Mapping directories and files does not mean "mounting" them.

You need to follow 2 steps:

1. Share the `/dev/nvme0n1` to the container

   ```
   docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/nvme0n1 -it saurabhd04/docker_fio
   ```
2. With the container running mount the `nvme0n1`:

   ```
   docker exec <container-id> mount /dev/nvme0n1 /mnt
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Robert! When I do 2nd step to mount the `ssd`, I get `permission denied` error.

Comment: I changed the approach. See the updated `docker run`

Comment: I see. I tried your updated approach. Now I don't get `permission denied` error but I now I get `mount:   /dev/ssd is not a block device`.

Comment: what is /dev/ssd? `file /dev/ssd`

Comment: `[root@node3 images]# file /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1: block special
`

It's a block device. `/dev/ssd` earlier was just an example, it is indeed `/dev/nvme0n1` SSD.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. I forced docker to use my SSD by using `devicemapper` and creating a LV on it. But strangely FIO gives very very poor iops performance through Docker in I/O benchmarking of my SSD.

Comment: Robert, I was able to manage run my benchmark tool on host SSD through Docker. I run `docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -it --device /dev/nvme0n1:/dev/xvda:rw saurabhd04/docker_fio`.

I guess adding `:rw` made all the difference.

Comment: Oh nice @SaurabhDeochake. Glad to hear that.